# JMeter: view Results Tree with parent and child samples after running in NON-GUI mode

Tags: tree, load, jmeter

In JMeter I created a test plan which contains several Transaction Controllers. I enabled "Generate parent sample", so that I get a real tree-structure in the Results Tree Listener. If I leave it disabled, all sub samples from different threads finish in one long list, making it hard to analyze the results to find out where something went wrong somewere down a thread's "branch" in the results tree.

When running this test plan with a smaller amount of threads in GUI-mode all is OK, but now I want to do a load test in non-gui mode. I can get results in a CSV, JTL or XML file, but those don't contain the sub samples, only the parents samples (the transaction controllers). When I load these results in the Results Tree in gui-mode (after finishing the non-gui-testrun) then I also don't get a nice results tree. The sub-samples weren't written to the file.

Is there a way to get a results tree with parent- and child samples (not just a long list without hierarchy) when running the test in non-gui-mode?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I already found the solution. In the `jmeter.properties` file I had to set

`jmeter.save.saveservice.subresults=true`

Then when I save the test results to an XML file, that file can viewed in the JMeter gui in a Results Tree Listener.

Comment: How do you save the results to an XML file? is the the .jtl file?